# How to get matching doc for term A and term B separately in AWS elastic search with single Query

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

Currently I'm able to do query on AWS elastic search to get matching doc's for single term. for that I'm using below query.

[image]

**Now I have a requirement to do query for multiple term and get there matching doc's**

Is there anyway to do query with multiple terms in single query with that we can get the matching terms separately for each term. which save lot of time for us

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) or [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) if you are querying text fields.